# How to insert records with angularjs php and mysql?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, crud

**I am using angularjs form with mysql database to store and retrieve data with mysql but im unable to perfrom crud operations with angularjs. im new to angularjs please help me with the same. below is my code for form.**

```
<form >                                 
<div class="control-group">                                         
    <label class="control-label" >Referal code:</label>
        <div class="controls">                      
            <input required type='text' class='span2' ng-model='tempUserData.referal_code'>                 
        </div>
</div>                                                  
<div class="control-group">                                     
    <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input required type="text" ng-model="tempUserData.emp_name" class="span2">                                             
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">                                     
    <label class="control-label">Date:</label>
    <div class="controls input-group">
    <datepicker>
        <input required type="text" ng-model="tempUserData.date" class="span2">
    </datepicker>                                                   
    </div>
</div>                                              
<div class="control-group">                                 
    <label class="control-label" >Date Of Joining:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <datepicker>
        <input required type="text" ng-model="tempUserData.dateofjoining" class="span2">
    </datepicker>                                               
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">                                     
    <label class="control-label" >Admin Name:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input required type="text" ng-model="tempUserData.admin" class="span2">                                                
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">                                     
    <label class="control-label" >Address:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input required type="text" ng-model="tempUserData.address" class="span2">                                              
    </div>
</div>                                      
<div class="control-group ">                                
    <label class="control-label">Company Name:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select ng-model="tempUserData.company_name" class="span2">
        <option ng-repeat="x in names" value="{{x.company_name}}">{{x.company_name}}</option>
        </select>                   
    </div>  
</div>                          
<div class="control-group">                                     
    <label class="control-label" >Title:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input required type="text" ng-model="tempUserData.title" class="span2">        
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-hide="tempUserData.id" ng-click="addUser()">&nbsp;Add Letter</button>
```

Script for this form:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['720kb.datepicker']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) 
{
    $http.get("http://www.adhr.adnacgroup.com/ADHRM/companyJson.php")
    .then(function(response) 
    {$scope.names = $scope.names = response.data.service;});
    $scope.addTask = function (task) {
    $http.post("addTask.php?task="+task).success(function(data){
        getTask();
        $scope.tempUserData.referal_code= "";
        $scope.tempUserData.emp_name = "";
        $scope.tempUserData.date = "";
        $scope.tempUserData.dateofjoining = "";
        $scope.tempUserData.admin = "";
        $scope.tempUserData.address = "";
        $scope.tempUserData.company_name = "";
        $scope.tempUserData.title = "";
      });
  };
});
</script>
```

Insert Query:

```
if(isset($_GET['task'])){
$task1 = $_GET['task'];
$task2 = $_GET['task'];
$task3 = $_GET['task'];
$task4 = $_GET['task'];
$task5 = $_GET['task'];
$task6 = $_GET['task'];
$task7 = $_GET['task'];
$task8 = $_GET['task'];
$query9=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `offer_letter`(`org_id`, `com_id`, `id`, `admin_name`, `address`, `offer_referal_code`, `com_name`, `title`, `date`, `dateofjoining`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION[org_id]."','".$task1."','".$task2."','".$task3."','".$task4."','".$task5."','".$task6."','".$task7."','".$task8."','".$task9."')");


$result = mysql_affected_rows($query);

echo $json_response = json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: I cant see where you are calling addTask() in your code?

Comment: @Shubhranshu insert query is my addTask.php

Answer (score 0):

To perform CRUD operation you have yo send data as post like as

```
$http({
   url:'addTask.php',
   method: 'POST',
   params:task
 })
```

In php script you get the parameters like

```
$task1 = $_POST['task'];
```